# 90 Jeep YJ: Identify part on top of engine?

Tags: jeep, part-identification, wrangler

What is this part from the top of the engine?
Part can be seen broken in this attached image.
[image]

### EDIT

Vehicle info:

- 1990 Jeep Wrangler YJ
- 6 cylinder 4.2L

Comment: Well *there's* yer problem! When you replace that valve check the line to make sure it's not developed any breaks.

Comment: @GdD I wish that was the only problem with this old rust bucket.

Comment: As a previous rust bucket owner my advice would be to look at your potential spend and decide whether to invest that money in what you have or something newer. I made the mistake of sinking a lot of money in an old car with loads of problems when I could have spent it on something more reliable. I ended up with loads of problems I couldn't fix myself in my front yard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a Positive Crankcase Ventilation (PCV) valve. Not sure which engine you have or I would have given you a couple of part numbers.

Well, guess I can give you both:

4-cyl

- FRAM FV200
- Standard Motor Products V207

6-cyl

- Standard Motor Products V236
- WVE 6P1016